# Xcode unable to fetch any public Swift Packages

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS2Ds.png)Suddenly my Xcode stopped fetching any public rep and asking for credentials. I am trying to add Alamofire. I am attaching the screenshots which ask for credentials. Also it doesn't show any details of the packages.

Tried clearing Derived data. Deleted Swift Packages caches. Deleted .netrc file.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS2Ds.png)